# Is there any particular way to set up files for Web Development?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, git, php, javascript

I've been working in...studying...Web Dev for about four years and I'm wondering if there is a particular file structure that's beneficial.
Example, I noticed one individual had a DEV folder directly on C drive, I've noticed another set up node.js directly on C instead of the Program Folder on C drive.
Usually when you run set up it has a route established but allows you to "browse" your folder structure...I assume so you can change it.
I've also been told to set up program files on one drive (...especially if it's an SSD so you don't encounter multiple rewrites) and project folders on another.

I do all the normal work; JS, I work in PHP so I normally have a WAMP, I have Android for React Native, I have VS Code, Git, etc. and I'm running Win 10 Pro on an SSD.

I hope this makes sense.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a particular file structure that's beneficial?

Unless an application requires items to be in particular folders, the most beneficial structure is likely the one you create for yourself (i.e. the one that works best for your development process).

> For example, I noticed one individual had a `DEV` folder directly on the `C:` drive. I've also noticed another set up `node.js` directly on `C:` instead of the `Program` folders on the `C:` drive.

This likely has a couple different functions, which aren't strictly related to web development:

- Folder paths with spaces can sometimes cause problems in cross-platform applications. Programs or scripts developed to be compatible with Mac or Linux may assume there will be no spaces in those paths (since spaces in paths are uncommon on those platforms) and may not run correctly if they encounter them (i.e. on Windows).
- The official Windows `Program` folders may limit access to programs or files in those folders. To avoid permission issues and the like (including problems storing files in those folders, such as logs, etc.), it's arguably wiser to install programs in another folder. This caveat also applies generally to Windows `User` folders as well.

> Usually when you run set up it has a route established but allows you to "browse" your folder structure...I assume so you can change it.

This is typically the case, yes.

> I've also been told to set up program files on one drive (...especially if it's an SSD so you don't encounter multiple rewrites) and project folders on another.

This is probably a good idea generally, again, not specific to web development. That said, newer SSDs probably aren't going to fail anytime soon from "excessive" rewrites and you should be backing up your important files regularly on a separate medium (DVD, external HD, etc.) anyway.